# In_App_Purchase provide information like if Payment has been successfull or not in In_App_Purchase. in flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

i have used [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin to do subscription in flutter.
now I know the inapppurchase provide all the status for subscription like purchased, restore, cancel, pending etc. but I want to know that in_app_purchase provide **purchased** status only after payment has been successful and amount deducted from user account or not?.